# Как связать таблицы с помощью мастера подстановок?

Tags: ms-access

Есть две таблицы.

```
Игрок:
      Серия паспорта
      Номер паспорта
      Фамилия
      Имя
      Отчество 
      Дата рождения
      Город проживания
      Профессия
Участие:
      Id участия
      Дата выхода игры в эфир (FK)
      Серия паспорта (FK)
      Номер паспорта (FK)
```

Как их связать с помощью мастера подстановок в MS Access? Я могу сделать мастер подстановки отдельно для поля [Серия паспорта] и отдельно для [Номер паспорта] в таблице Участие. Но тогда в схеме данных появится еще одна таблица Игрок1. И как сделать так, чтобы при выборе значения для поля [Серия паспорта] автоматически заполнилось поле [Номер паспорта]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Добавьте в таблицу "Игрок" поле "ИгрокID" (Ключевое - Счётчик)
2. Добавьте в таблицу "Участие" поле "ID_Игрока" (Длинное целое)
3. Свяжите таблицы  Игрок.ИгрокID 1:M Участие.ID_Игрока
4. Удалите из таблицы "Участие" дублирующиеся данные игрока- поля "Серия паспорта (FK)" и "Номер паспорта (FK)"

Теперь вы сможете назначать игроков на игру просто указывая их ID